# How to use Advanced Sheets Service API with google script to avoid script errors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

It has been brought to my attention in a previous post that using Advanced Sheets Service API would be a solution for a script that keep failing with an exception timeout.

However, I am quite the beginner with both google script and not to mention the Sheets API service.

If someone could help me implement this workaround, I would be very grateful.

The script is

```
function removed() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 9, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 16);
  var formulas = range.getFormulas().map(r => r.splice(1));
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a, ...b], i) => a == 'Removed' ? b : formulas[i]);
  range.offset(0, 1, values.length, 15).setValues(values);
}
```

or

```
function removed() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 9, sheet.getLastRow(), 16);
  var formulas = range.getFormulas().map(r => r.splice(1));
  var values = range.getValues().map(([a, ...b], i) => a == 'Removed' ? b : formulas[i]);
  range.offset(0, 1, values.length, 15).setValues(values);
}
```

and the consequent error is

```
Nov 3, 2022, 3:23:12 PM Error   Exception: Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id xxx
    at removed(Remove Formula:6:41)
```

Comment: While this question is no more a duplicate, you've done no research and no attempts to solve the problem yourself. See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: @TheMaster Unfortunately, I find this very complicated and advanced. I am nevertheless thankful of the resources you shared in the previous post. I did read those and will continue to, but I just found it all very hard, even the script I have I am not very well acquainted with. I just dont know how to use .map and really have no idea where to start to put it with Sheets API. Just looking at the post below and I really dont even know where to start.

Comment: The time between closing the previous question and you asking this question is barely a hour. That's not enough time to get familiar with any subject.  Secondly, what code did you attempt to change? What error did you run into? Have you tried searching and fixing that error? Have you repeated this cycle multiple times? That is what is known as practice. And practice brings familiarity. Finally, questions are contributions to the community, just like a answer is. Don't ask a question because you want to know the answer. Ask a question because you want others to know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started here is an example of how to use Sheets API to get values.

I created a simple spreadsheet.

[image]

Now a script to get the values B2:E5.

```
function removed() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let range = sheet.getName()+"!"+getRangeA1(2,2)+":"+getRangeA1(sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
    let values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spread.getId(),range);
    console.log(values);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function getRangeA1(row,col) {
  try {
    let colNum = col;
    let colName = "";
    let modulo = 0;
    while( colNum > 0 ) {
      modulo = (colNum - 1) % 26;
      colName = String.fromCharCode(65 + modulo) + colName;
      colNum = Math.floor((colNum - modulo) / 26);
    }
    return colName+row;
  }
  catch(err) {
    throw "Error in getRangeA1: "+err;
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
8:41:59 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:42:00 AM  Info    { values: 
   [ [ '12', '22', '32', '42' ],
     [ '13', '23', '33', '43' ],
     [ '14', '24', '34', '44' ],
     [ '15', '25', '35', '45' ] ],
  range: 'Sheet1!B2:E5',
  majorDimension: 'ROWS' }
8:42:00 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Reference:

- [Advanced Sheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets)

Comment: Thank you for the help and sample script. However, I am very new to scripts and until today i had not heard of the Advanced Sheet Service. Unfortunately, at this point i dont know to use the sample script to meet my script needs. Would you be able to further help me? Either way thanks for the time taken on your answer.

Comment: "Advanced Sheet Service." was in your title.